Увеличить каждое число в списке на десять процентов
Кто может подскажите, как каждое число в списке умножить на десять процентов
Вот пробы кода
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
percent = 10
for i in l:
    i = l + (l * percent / 100)
print(i)


Умножить на 10%? Вопрос неконкретный. Если Вы имеете ввиду, взять 10% от числа и умножить наше число на 10% от него, то так:
number := 100
tenPercent := number * (number * 0.10)

(код на go, но смысл думаю понятен)

Судя по всему, правильная формулировка вопроса - в теме, а не в тексте )

Спасибо, разобрался)

for i in l:
    i = l + (l * percent / 100)

Ваша переменная цикла i не имеет обратной связи со списком. Она получает значение из списка на каждой итерации, но обратно в список вы должны сами его записать. Например, для этого можно использовать обращение по индексу (здесь переменная i уже не элемент списка, а индекс в списке):
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] *= 1 + percent / 100

